# Reactive native keeping *.web.tsx in a seperate folder

Tags: react-native, webpack, react-native-web

I have `react-native` + `react-native-web` both in same project and it is working fine.

I have code `MyScreen.tsx` + `MyScreen.web.tsx` the `.web.tsx` file is perfectly picked by webpack and working fine

But `MyScreen.tsx` + `MyScreen.web.tsx` are kept in the same folder

My question is How do I separate it ?

This is my webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single'
  },
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'index.web.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    clean: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.web.tsx', '.web.ts', '.tsx', '.ts', '.web.js', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    },
```